# Maximum number of canary releases per sprint in scrum

Tags: release, production, release-management, canary-deployment, sre

My question is, is there a limit to the number of Canary releases or not? Or is there a relation between the number of Canary releases and the final releases? For example, if we agree to have a maximum of two releases in each sprint, we can have 100 Canary releases in the same sprint (assuming that the resources and infrastructure are available) and many of these Canary releases have nothing to do with the two main releases.

The problem that exists in our team now is that our sub-team in the SYSTEM team prepares a canary version for different tasks, but on the other hand, our colleagues in the SRE and DEVOPS team do not have the opportunity to canary all the versions. And on the other hand, we don't have an automatic system for canary, now our question is where the problem comes from? should we increase the number of our SRE forces so that all canary versions have a chance to go up or not, maybe it's more correct that the number of our canary versions Reduce during a sprint

Comment: There is no limit to how much canary releases you should be doing. It depends of course per company and environment. You would do canary release test your code before releasing to production. What's the reason you do 100 vs 10 canary releases? why is there two different releases per sprint? Pretty sure there's a good reason behind it. But the main purpose of canary testing is to test many different environment your code has to go through with different configurations.. Therefore, how do you know the `Canary releases have nothing to do with the two main releases`?

Comment: `we don't have an automatic system for canary, now our question is where the problem comes from?` I think the answer to this question is in the statement itself. You don't have automation. Why not? You have DevOps/SRE and their main role is to provide that solution.

Comment: I'm also sensing that the DevOps/SRE team gets pulled to do 2+ canary releases for the other team. Here's just one suggestion, this is what we do in ours is - every end of sprint, we cut off the dev branch (where all features are) to create a release candidate branch which is basically a bundle of changes - done on all our repositories. Do rc test. If passed, do canary tests. If passed, release to production. We do this with configuration management tools. This way DevOps / SRE doesn't get pulled to pushing and doing test for the other team in the middle of sprints.

Comment: One of the most modern way is for the DevOps to just focus on providing the platform for other teams (in your case the SYSTEM team) to do their own releases. DevOps/SRE focuses on making sure the platform is always up and running and making sure the new version gets delivered to the intended destination whether it's for Canary/Dev/Staging/Production. And of course, having a monitoring tool that everyone can use.